# Debugging undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(routeConfigs)')

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm using Expo and React Native to create a simple iOS app. I am currently getting this error and have no idea how to fix it. I've tried various other solutions on Stack Overflow to no avail.

[image: ![enter image description here]

My code is:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Here is my `HomeScreen.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function HomeScreen () {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Welcome Home!</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

My packages:

```
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "safey",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.10",
        "expo": "~45.0.0",
        "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "17.0.2",
        "react-native": "0.68.1",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.4.2",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^2.8.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.5",
        "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
        "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
        "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
        "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try importing the stack navigator like the following and see if it fixes the issue?

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! I swear I tried that but must've not.

Comment: You are welcome. No worries, it happens to the best of us.